# Use Facebook Graph API to disconnect a Facebook Page from a Facebook App

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a website with a Facebook App that allows Facebook users to connect their Facebook pages to the App so that the website can use that Page in different ways.

But I cannot find a way to disconnect the Facebook Page from the App using a Facebook API (probably the Graph API?). The problem is that Facebook keeps sending webhook events as long as the Page is connected to the app.

Is there such a call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's done via the `subscribed_apps` edge on the page. Same as you can add a subscription via this, you can also remove it again.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/subscribed_apps/#Deleting

Comment: Thank you! But does this mean that there is no way to disconnect a page from an app, other than removing the subscriptions? (I am not sure I really need to do the disconnect, but still...)

Comment: Not sure in what way the could be considered "connected" to begin with, other than the webhook subscription.

Comment: I still have a valid page access token that can be used to do stuff with the page.

Comment: Yeah, sure, but that is completely independent from the webhook updates. I don't know if there actually is a way to invalidate a specific page token, without removing the necessary permissions from the user account through which it was granted.

Comment: Is there a way to independently subscribe to webhook events for an Instagram page and a Facebook Page? It is not possible send the Instagram Page ID to the endpoint you mentioned, but both pages uses the same page access token.

Comment: No, I don't think that is possible. The "connection" to an IG creator/business account, is always made via the connected FB page.

Comment: Interesting. A created a follow up question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73383520/independently-subscribe-to-instagram-and-facebook-page-webhooks