# Independently subscribe to Instagram and Facebook Page webhooks?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, facebook-webhooks

I know it is possible to subscribe to webhooks (for a Meta/Facebook App) for a specific Facebook page by using [https://graph.facebook.com/{pageId}/subscribed_apps?subscribed_fields={fields}&access_token={token}](https://graph.facebook.com/%7BpageId%7D/subscribed_apps?subscribed_fields=%7Bfields%7D&access_token=%7Btoken%7D) but how does this work for Instagram pages? The only text I have found about it states the following:

`Note: You cannot use the subscribed_fields parameter to configure or subscribe to Webhooks for Instagram. You must use your app dashboard to subscribe to Instagram Webhooks` (from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/subscribed_apps/)

But it sounds a bit weird that a customer using our App cannot connect their Instagram page to our App and have webhooks delivered, without me as an App-owner doing manual stuff in the app dashboard.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to subscribe instagram page you should just go to instagram entry on the developer facebook account webhooks and then subscribe to a field that you want to receive notifications .  your facebook page should be associated to your instagram business account .

N.B For the feed of instagram we have only comments field